# how to remove the first comma in a string in excel vba

Tags: excel, parsing, vba

If I have a string: `"foo, bar" baz, test, blah`, how do I remove a specific comma, i.e. not all of them, but just one of my choosing?

with [Replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php) and [INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php) it looks like I have not know where the comma is.  The problem is, I'll only want to remove the comma if it appears between quotation marks.

So, I may want to remove the first comma and I may not.

Put more clearly, if there is a comma between a set of quotation marks, I need to remove it.  if not, then there's nothing to do.  But, I can't just remove all the commas, as I need the others in the string.

Comment: What if you had `"foo, bar", baz, "test, blah"`? How do you know which comma is "between a set of quotation marks"? Sounds like you have an issue with a CSV creator/parser, and you're trying to fix the wrong problem.

Comment: its a fair question. there strings are always going to be: `"name", stat1, stat2`.  The only question is if there will be a comma in the name like `Facebook, Inc`.

Comment: Do you want to remove ALL the commas that show up between quotation marks or just the first one?

Comment: all commas between quotation marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with Regexp in this way:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim TXT As String
    TXT = """foo, bar"" baz, test, blah"

    Debug.Print TXT

    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With objRegExp
        .Global = True  '
        .Pattern = "(""\w+)(,)(\s)(\w+"")"

    Debug.Print .Replace(TXT, "$1$3$4")

    End With


End Sub
```

It works as expected for the sample value you have provided but could require additional adjustments by changing `.Pattern` for more complicated text.

**EDIT** If you want to use this solution as an Excel function than use this code:

```
Function RemoveCommaInQuotation(TXT As String)

    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With objRegExp
        .Global = True 
        .Pattern = "(""\w+)(,)(\s)(\w+"")"

    RemoveCommaInQuotation = .Replace(TXT, "$1$3$4")

    End With


End Function
```

Comment: I would recommend a pattern of `"(""[^""]*),([^""]*"")"` and a replacement of `"$1$2"`.  This covers additional cases, such as `"Facebook,Inc"` (no space) and `"Facebook, Inc."` (has a '.' which is not matched by '\w')

Comment: @Blackhawk, thanks for the suggestion, I voted it up. As I stated in my answer: `It works as expected for the sample value you have provided but could require additional adjustments by changing .Pattern for more complicated text.` Moreover, any other alternative patterns are welcome :).

Comment: great answer!! thanks!  can you point to a resource so I can read up on regex for excel vba?  All I find are articles.

Comment: @dwstein, try [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic2) or [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/A_1336-Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html) or [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Ugh.  Here's another way

```
Public Function foobar(yourStr As String) As String
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(yourStr, Chr(34))
    parts(1) = Replace(parts(1), ",", "")
    foobar = Join(parts, Chr(34))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

With some error-checking for odd number of double quotes:

```
Function myremove(mystr As String) As String
    Dim sep As String
    sep = """"
    Dim strspl() As String
    strspl = Split(mystr, sep, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
    Dim imin As Integer, imax As Integer, nstr As Integer, istr As Integer
    imin = LBound(strspl)
    imax = UBound(strspl)
    nstr = imax - imin
    If ((nstr Mod 2) <> 0) Then
      myremove = "Odd number of double quotes"
      Exit Function
    End If
    For istr = imin + 1 To imax Step 2
      strspl(istr) = Replace(strspl(istr), ",", "")
    Next istr
    myremove = Join(strspl(), """")
End Function
```